# What are the possible issues and Highlighted features of Magento 2.3.2

Tags: bug, magento2.3.2, features

**Magento Commerce 2.3.2 Release Notes has released on June 29.**

Patch code and release notes published on June 25, 2019. Release notes last updated on July 8, 2019.

1. What are the highlighted features in this version directly as a list
2. What are the possible Issues
3. what are the differences between this version and the previous version.

Answer (score 1):

For what I know modules might get issues that are dependend on the Stock-Plugin that has been removed with 2.3.2. For example Smile Elasticsuite had issues here.

Answer (score 1):

> Storefront accessibility improvements

**New Features for 2.3.2**

- [Amazon Sales Channel 2.0.0](https://marketplace.magento.com/magento-module-amazon.html), supports US, Canada, Mexico only.
- [Google Shopping ads Channel 1.1.1](https://marketplace.magento.com/magento-google-shopping-ads.html)
- Bluefoot Data Migration Tool

> GraphQL

- Expanded GraphQL coverage for cart/checkout
- Caching for GraphQL queries

> Performance Improvements

- Significant storefront page load time improvements under load (20%+)
- Asynchronous operations in Admin

> Increased focus on Security

- Google reCAPTCHA module for PayPal Payflow checkout
- Amazon Pay PSD2 compliance

For issues it's too early to get you details about it because it is more based on people experience. As much as people experience this recent release we will get to know about it.

References:

https://magecomp.com/blog/magento-2-3-2-is-released-jun-25th-everything-need-know/

https://www.mageplaza.com/blog/magento-2-3-2-release-notes.html

**I hope this will help**